# spotify SIGSEGV error "Warning: GTK2 does not support Wayland!"

Tags: linux, gtk, spotify, segmentation-fault

I'm currently using Arch Linux operating system. I just ran **pacman** **-Syu** command that updates all packages so I don't know which one is causing the problem. I then tried to start spotify and got this error:

```
Warning: GTK2 does not support Wayland!
Pułapka debuggera/breakpoint (zrzut pamięci) - in english "trap of debugger/breakpoint (segmentation fault)"
```

How can I fix it?

**edit:**

After running spotify as root I'm receiving only this message:

```
Pułapka debuggera/breakpoint
```

even without **(zrzut pamięci)** - "segmentation fault"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating spotify to lastest 1:1.1.10.546-3 version it works correctly